# Fitting a Voigt distribution - never finishes

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I'm trying to fit a Voigt distribution to some measurements, but no matter what I try Mathematica simply never finishes, even if I do `MaxIterations -> 1` and very low precision goals. For example you can take this data:

```
DD = 100; theta2B = 13.742; Lamda = 0.999047433;
ϕ[DD_, theta2_] := 2 Pi DD (Sin[theta2/360*Pi] - Sin[theta2B/360*Pi])/Lamda;
profile = 1/ϕ[DD, theta2]^2 - Sin[2 ϕ[DD, theta2]]/ϕ[DD, theta2]^3 + (1 - 
  Cos[2 ϕ[DD, theta2]])/(2 ϕ[DD, theta2]^4);
data = Transpose[{Table[i, {i, 7, 20, 0.01}], Table[profile, {theta2, 7, 20, 0.01}]}];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

And function definition:

```
voigt[I_, δ_, σ_, x_] := I*PDF[VoigtDistribution[δ, σ], {x}];
```

And then fitting using:

```
Clear[a, x, δ, σ];
model3 = voigt[a, δ, σ, x];
fit3 = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  model3, {{a, 1}, {δ, 1}, {σ, 1}}, x, 
  Method -> NMinimize];
a = fit3[[1, 2, 1, 2]];
δ = fit3[[1, 2, 2, 2]];
σ = fit3[[1, 2, 3, 2]];
fitplot2 = LogPlot[model3, {x, 0, 8.5}]
```

The only error message that I sometimes get is that the output is unreal. The output from voigt[] is on the form {y + .0i} (I don't know why it's in {}), so I've tried to only take the real part.

Comment: The `VoigtDistribution` is peaked around zero (`Median[VoigtDistribution[a, b]] = 0`; play also with `Manipulate[
 Plot[voigt[a, b, c, x], {x, -5, 5}], {a, 1, 20}, {b, 1, 20}, {c, 1, 
  20}]`) and your `data` is peaked (rather narrowly) around `14`.

Comment: Oops, I accidently gave you the non-zero-centered data...

Comment: In your definition of voigt you use capital I, which is the complex number I. I suggest you use different variable (E, D, I are symbols). Also,  PDF[VoigtDistribution[δ, σ], {x}] threads PDF over the list {x} - if you want value of PDF at a point, use PDF[VoigtDistribution[δ, σ], x].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `VoigtDistribution` is centered around zero, and the OP's `data` has a narrow peak at around `14`. Let's shift it to zero (crudely):

```
pos = Max@Position[(Transpose@data)[[2]], (Transpose@data)[[2]] // Max]
```

> 675

```
peak = (Transpose@data)[[1, pos]]
```

> 13.74

```
data = Transpose[Transpose@data - {peak, 0}];
plot = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Second - and important - it is a matter of good starting values for the parameters for `NonlinearModelFit`. Playing with

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[voigt[a, b, c, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 1}}],
  {a, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {b, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {c, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

I choose `{1, 0.2, 0.2}`.

```
model3 = voigt[a, b, c, x];
fit3 = NonlinearModelFit[data, model3, {{a, 0.8}, {b, 0.2}, {c, 0.2}}, x]
```

which with **no errors** gives

```
Normal@fit3
```

[image]

```
a = fit3[[1, 2, 1, 2]]
b = fit3[[1, 2, 2, 2]]
c = fit3[[1, 2, 3, 2]]
fitplot2 = Plot[model3, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
```

> 0.742524
>
> 0.0809207
>
> 0.223623

and

```
Show[fitplot2, plot]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally gave you the wrong data (it should of course be zero-centered). With your method it's working for me now, but when I used NMinimize method before submitting here on this relatively simple data it still hadn't finished after one hour.

Comment: First, it's `Method -> "NMinimize"`, not `Method -> NMinimize` as in your code (see the docs). Second, `"NMinimize"` indeed runs long enough to not wait for the result. On the other hand, `"Newton"` works (although takes twice as long as the automatic methods). You can also play with other methods (listed in the docs). `"LevenbergMarquardt"` also works in a time even slightly shorter than the automatic method.